Match list to a pattern
I want to match a list to a pattern, but MatchQ is not doing the job as needed. For example, I need:
input1={1,2,3};
input2={3,2,3};
Match[input1,{a,b,c}] // True
Match[input1,{a,b,a}] // False
Match{input2,{a,b,c}] // False
Match[input2,{a,b,a}] // True

Is there a way to do this with existing functions?

@Nasser but that fails the third test case.

What you're asking for can be done if you provide a more specific description of your matching criteria. For the {a,b,c} case, do you mean {a,a+1,a+2} or do you just mean that the list is free of duplicates? Similarly for your {a,b,a} case, should {1,1,1} match that or do you require that a and b are distinct? And unless your match criteria is actually the most simple case implied, you're probably better off with using something other than MatchQ.

Yeah, I noticed that. what I'm saying is that the OP wants MatchQ[input2, {a_, b_, c_}] to return False. (Which, of course, it never will, but the OP wants a pattern that both matches on input1 but fails on input2.)

input1 = {1, 2, 3};
input2 = {3, 2, 3};
MatchQ[input1, {a_, b_, c_} /; And[a != b, b != c, a != c]]
MatchQ[input1, {a_, b_, a_} /; (a != b)]
MatchQ[input2, {a_, b_, c_} /; And[a != b, b != c, a != c]]
MatchQ[input2, {a_, b_, a_} /; (a != b)]


True
False
False
True

/; (Condition) allows patterns to be conditioned, and allows the restriction that a, b, and c be distinct to be enforced.

Thank you! How can I use this in a Switch[] function to filter for the correct pattern matching an input list?

You can simplify the condition to a!=b!=c (see the fourth bullet point in the details section of the documentation)
